# firefox audio very noisy and garbled

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, web-browsers, audio-playback

My firefox version is:
 firefox:armhf 49.0+build4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
I have an issue of very poor/very noisy/ audio when I play any video files.
(be it from youtube or mp4 files itself.)
Video is good.
Omxplayer works fine both video/audio.
I have rpi 3 withe jessie.

Comment: Does this apply to all audio, or just web based? Are you using HDMI or 3.5mm stereo jack? Does the garbled noise go away if you turn the volume up beyond about 75%? I've covered this in a number of places. 3.5mm jack audio uses two of the output pins as PWM DACs. Doesn't work at all well at low volume.

Comment: both web based and files (when using firefox) I am using HDMI.  It does not go away on increasing volume.

Comment: My comment doesn't apply, then. HDMI should work. Suggest looking or a CPU monitoring tool? Check you haven't got something else hogging the processor.